# A quick doubt on Archimedes' algorithm for calculating $\pi$

Tags: calculus

I'm having a little trouble understanding the following step in Archimedes' algorithm for calculating $\pi$ presented in Simmons' Calculus with Analytic Geometry, pg. 216:

Let $p_n$ be an n-sided polygon inscribed in the unit circle, as shown in the figure:
[image]

If $\theta$ is half the vertex angle, then we have
$$\theta=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{360º}{n}$$

My doubt is: Why is $ \theta=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{360º}{n}$? Thanks.

Comment: The sides are of equal length, that means the angles must be of equal size, that is $\frac{1}{2n}$ of a revolution, which is $360 ^\circ$

Answer (score 2):

Hint : The angle in the middle is halfed. All the angles together give $360°$